# show mouse cursor in 1280*1024 video mode - assembly language

Tags: assembly, cursor, mouse, x86-16, bochs

Sample Output:

[image]

I tried to get mouse click position, but when I click on the screen,the mouse becomes hidden, but the clicks get correct positions! that I display them
although I use the interrupt that make the mouse cursor visible!
Can I make the mouse visible or do I have to make my own cursor by get positions?

My sample code is:

```
include MainMacro.inc
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
OUTPUT1              DB    5 DUP('$') 
OUTPUT2              DB    5 DUP('$')
OUTPUTS              DB    '     $' 

.CODE        
MAIN PROC FAR             
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX 

        MOV AX,4F02h                        ;OPEN 1280*1024 SCREEN
        MOV BX,107h  
        INT 10h  

        mov ax,7                            ;SET HORIZONTAL RANGE
        MOV CX,0
        MOV DX,1279
        int 33h  

        mov ax,8                            ;SET VERTICAL RANGE
        MOV CX,0
        MOV DX,1023
        int 33h 

        ;;;;;;;;;;;;; 

        mov ax, 1           ;TURN MOUSE CURSOR ON.
        int 33h         
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        JMP MAINLOOP
        REL0:
            MOV AX,6
            MOV BX,0
            INT 33H
            CMP BX,0
            JNE REL0
            JMP MOUSE              ;IF LEFT BUTTON IS RELEASED
        REL1:
            MOV AX,6
            MOV BX,1
            INT 33H
            CMP BX,0
            JNE REL1
            JMP MOUSE             ;IF RIGHT BUTTON IS RELEASED

        MOUSE:
        PUSHA
            REGISTER_TO_STRING 4 0AH CX OUTPUT1   ;PUT X THE VALUE IN OUTPUT
        POPA 
        PUSHA
            REGISTER_TO_STRING 4 0AH DX OUTPUT2   ;PUT Y THE VALUE IN OUTPUT
        POPA
        DISPLAY_STRING OUTPUT1  
        DISPLAY_STRING OUTPUTS
        DISPLAY_STRING OUTPUT2 
        LINE_DOWN 1
        MAINLOOP:
            MOV AX,6          ;LEFT BUTTON PREESED
            MOV BX,0
            INT 33H
            CMP BX,0
            JNE REL0

            MOV AX,6           ;RIGHT BUTTON PREESED
            MOV BX,1
            INT 33H
            CMP BX,0
            JNE REL1
            JMP MAINLOOP


        HLT 
        MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: I think the BIOS has some simple HW cursor, drawn by `xor`-ing with image data, if you will switch it on, and if it works correctly in your SVGA mode (try first in some classic VGA mode, like 12h (640x480x16 colours) to see if the BIOS mouse is visible there). But to get any decent graphically good looking cursor you will have to draw it manually any way, to do a full over-draw over background graphic instead of `xor`.

Comment: And about the mouse cursor hiding upon click. Do you mean your OS cursor? Because upon first click on the dosbox window, the dosbox will capture the mouse exclusively, and emulate the DOS mouse, so the host-OS cursor is hidden. To release the mouse from dosbox the default shortcut is "Ctrl+F10", that should return the mouse back to host-OS. (but that is completely invisible to the original DOS and would not exist in pure DOS ... what you would get in pure DOS is what you see when the mouse is exclusively captured by dosbox)